# Alias a JSON-LD keyword and simultaneously provide a @context for it

Tags: json, json-ld, linked-data, turtle-rdf

I have the following JSON document (based on GitHub API output):

```json
{
  "@id": "https://github.com/octadocs/octadocs",
  "license": {
    "key": "mit",
    "name": "MIT License",
    "spdx_id": "MIT",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz"
  }
}
```

Using JSON-LD, I'd like to retrieve the following triple from this:

```
<https://github.com/octadocs/octadocs>
    <https://octadocs.io/github/license>
    <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT> .
```

- I can interpret `license` as `https://octadocs.io/github/license` with `@vocab` (I would like to use it globally actually, for all properties);
- I can specify `@type` for `spdx_id` to make its value an IRI;
- and I finally can define a `@context` with a `@base` for it, to convert `MIT` string into an spdx.org reference.

Context:

```json
{
  "@base": "https://octadocs.io/github/",
  "@vocab": "https://octadocs.io/github/",
  "spdx_id": {
    "@type": "@id",
    "@context": {
      "@base": "https://spdx.org/licenses/"
    }
  }
}
```

See a [demonstration](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Foctadocs.io%2Fgithub%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Foctadocs.io%2Fgithub%2F%22%2C%22spdx_id%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fspdx.org%2Flicenses%2F%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Foctadocs%2Foctadocs%22%2C%22license%22%3A%7B%22key%22%3A%22mit%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22MIT%20License%22%2C%22spdx_id%22%3A%22MIT%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.github.com%2Flicenses%2Fmit%22%2C%22node_id%22%3A%22MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz%22%7D%7D) in JSON-LD playground.

But, this creates a slightly different structure than the desired one:

```
<https://github.com/octadocs/octadocs> <https://octadocs.io/github/license> _:b0 .
_:b0 <https://octadocs.io/github/spdx_id> <https://spdx.org/licenses/MIT> .
```

I'd like to avoid the blank node.

This can be achieved by JSON-LD keyword aliasing:

```json
{
  ...,
  "spdx_id": "@id"
}
```

but how to simultaneously

- alias the property,
- and define things like `@type` and `@context` for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is remove the `@vocab` definition within `license`, alias `spdx_id` to `@id`, and remove the default vocabulary. This treats the object value of `license` as a node object (really node reference) as all keys other than `spdx_id` are ignored. See playground link [here](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Foctadocs.io%2Fgithub%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Foctadocs.io%2Fgithub%2F%22%2C%22license%22%3A%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40vocab%22%3Anull%2C%22spdx_id%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Foctadocs%2Foctadocs%22%2C%22license%22%3A%7B%22key%22%3A%22mit%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22MIT%20License%22%2C%22spdx_id%22%3A%22MIT%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.github.com%2Flicenses%2Fmit%22%2C%22node_id%22%3A%22MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz%22%7D%7D).

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "https://octadocs.io/github/",
    "@vocab": "https://octadocs.io/github/",
    "license": {
      "@context": {
        "@vocab": null,
        "spdx_id": "@id"
      }
    }
  },
  "@id": "https://github.com/octadocs/octadocs",
  "license": {
    "key": "mit",
    "name": "MIT License",
    "spdx_id": "MIT",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/licenses/mit",
    "node_id": "MDc6TGljZW5zZTEz"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not think to use nested `@context` here. But I am still a little bit puzzled. How could I specify that the `@base` for `spdx_id` (not for other keys in `license` block) is http://spdx.org/licenses/? Otherwise, this key maps to https://octadocs.io/github/MIT.

Comment: After some thought... It seems okay to add `"@base": "http://spdx.org/licenses/"` to the nested context and it works, not causing any unwanted side effects. Thanks a lot again!